Spring Boot Thymeleaf Modal Form Not Saving Data to Database
I'm working on a Spring Boot project with Thymeleaf where users can create appointments. The appointment creation form is in a modal popup, and users must be authenticated to access it. The form data is successfully sent to the controller, but the appointment is not being saved to the database.
Here is my setup:
Appointment Entity:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Appointment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long appointmentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    private String name;
    private String companyName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String address;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "appointment_employee",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    )
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = ServiceType.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "appointment_services", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "service_type")
    private Set<ServiceType> serviceTypes;

    @Column(name = "additional_service")
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> additionalServices;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "appointment")
    @Nullable
    private Invoice invoice;

    private String appointmentDate;
    private String completionDate;
    private String status;
}


AppointmentForm DTO:
@Data
public class AppointmentForm {
    private Long userId;
    private String name;
    private String companyName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String address;
    private Set<String> serviceTypes;
    private String appointmentDate;
    private Set<String> additionalServices;
}

Thymeleaf form
<div id="appointment-modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h1>Create Appointment</h1>
        <div th:if="${success}" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            Appointment successfully created!
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/createAppointment}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="companyName">Company</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" name="companyName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address">Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Service Type</label>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="serviceTypes" value="COMMERCIAL"> Commercial
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="serviceTypes" value="RESIDENTIAL"> Residential
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="serviceTypes" value="KITCHEN_CLEANING"> Kitchen Cleaning
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="serviceTypes" value="BATHROOM_CLEANING"> Bathroom Cleaning
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="appointmentDate">Appointment Date</label>
                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="appointmentDate" name="appointmentDate" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Additional Services</label>
                <div id="additionalServicesContainer"></div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addAdditionalServiceField()">Add Additional Service</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId" th:value="${userId}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create Appointment</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


Controller
@Controller
public class AppointmentController {

    @Autowired
    private AppointmentService appointmentService;

    @PostMapping("/createAppointment")
    public String createAppointment(@ModelAttribute AppointmentForm appointmentForm, Model model) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Form data: " + appointmentForm);
            System.out.println("User ID from form: " + appointmentForm.getUserId());
            appointmentService.saveAppointment(appointmentForm);
            return "redirect:/userProfile?success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Error creating appointment: " + e.getMessage());
            return "userProfile";
        }
    }
}


Service
@Service
public class AppointmentService {

    @Autowired
    private AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void saveAppointment(AppointmentForm appointmentForm) {
        System.out.println("In saveAppointment");

        Appointment appointment = new Appointment();

        // Fetch user by userId from appointmentForm
        User user = userRepository.findById(appointmentForm.getUserId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found"));

        // Debugging log
        System.out.println("After fetching the user");
        System.out.println("User id in the saveAppointment method: " + user.getId());
        System.out.println("User: " + user);

        appointment.setUser(user);
        appointment.setCompanyName(appointmentForm.getCompanyName());
        appointment.setName(appointmentForm.getName());
        appointment.setEmail(appointmentForm.getEmail());
        appointment.setPhoneNumber(appointmentForm.getPhoneNumber());
        appointment.setAddress(appointmentForm.getAddress());

        // Convert serviceTypes from String to Enum
        Set<ServiceType> serviceTypes = appointmentForm.getServiceTypes().stream()
                .map(ServiceType::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        appointment.setServiceTypes(serviceTypes);

        // Set additional services
        appointment.setAdditionalServices(appointmentForm.getAdditionalServices());

        // Set appointment date
        appointment.setAppointmentDate(appointmentForm.getAppointmentDate());
        
        // Debugging log for appointment object
        System.out.println("Appointment to be saved: " + appointment);

        // Save appointment to the database
        System.out.println("Saving appointment");
        try {
            appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
            System.out.println("Appointment saved");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error saving appointment: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


The form data is correctly sent to the controller and the saveAppointment method in the service is called, but the data is not being saved to the database. The only log I see is "In saveAppointment".
Debugging Steps Taken:

Verified that the form data is correctly bound to the AppointmentForm.
Checked that the saveAppointment method is being called.
Added debug logs to ensure the method execution flow.
Ensured the repository is correctly injected and used.
Checked for database constraints and entity mappings.

Once I create an appointment, it should be saved to the database.

I guess chatGPT is my only option :(

can you share a reproducer ? it will be easy to investigate that way.
